# Managing a Juniper EX4300 In Band

Tags: vlan, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex, irb

Currently, our ex4300 are managed in band using irb.20.

show configuration interfaces irb

unit 20 {

```
family inet6 {
    address 2001:db8:1::252/64;
```

show configuration routing-options

rib inet6.0 {

```
static {
    route ::/0 next-hop 2001:db8:1::254 (this is the MX10003 router's sub-interface IP).
```

vlan 20 is our MGMT vlan 
Vlan 10 is our production vlan

I need to restrict management plane traffic that is destined to the switch. For example, ssh traffic destined for `2001:db8:1::252` needs to be sourced from our NOC network (`2001:db8:10::/64`). The problem is when I apply a firewall filter to irb.20, it's checking everything coming through, even if it's not destined for `2001:db8:1::252`, because we have other access ports in vlan 20. I figure the best way to fix this is to manage the switch with a different logical interface. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this to work. I've tried configuring lo0, vme0, me0, and fxp0 all to no avail. When I configured the aforementioned interfaces, I gave them the inet6 address `2001:db8:1::200/64`. I'm not certain what I'm missing, but any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should not use Global IPv6 addresses that belong to someone else, and the `1000::/64` is a RESERVED range that should not be used at all.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I, in fact, am not using those specific addresses. I just quickly used them to give as an easy example.

Comment: IANA has set aside `2001:db8::/32` for such examples, and you can subnet that to create fake addresses, but do not use real Global addresses or RESERVED addresses for that.

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks Ron.

Comment: You should get familiar with the [IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml).

Comment: For an EX4300 you can use lo0, me0, or vme0 if it's configured in a virtual-chassis, fxp0 is for other platforms.  That said, what about configuring those types of interfaces didn't work?  Configuration errors, reachability issues, etc?

Comment: Jordan, I figured loopback unit 0 would be the best. So, specifically, when I configure it with the 2001:db8:1::200/64 address, I'm unable to ping the gateway 2001:db8:1::252. And from the gateway router, I'm unable to ping the loopback 0 address of the switch.

Comment: If you choose to use lo0, you have to advertise its reachability to the network somehow, you also have to ensure a valid return path.

Comment: @JordanHead do you mean make the switch part of our IGP?

Comment: That’s one option, sure - the design you choose just depends on your network.  I believe Jeff Wheelers answer is an option as well.

Comment: @JordanHead Thank you. I didn't even realize Jeff Wheeler's comment was there (first time asking a question on this platform). I think this will work perfectly. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Junos allows you to restrict control-plane traffic -- including SSH, routing protocol traffic, etc. -- by applying a filter to the lo0 interface.  This is true even if you have not configured a loopback IP address.

For example, you can allow SSH and SNMP traffic only from 192.0.2.0/24, but allow all other traffic (default-allow) with the following configuration-fragment.

Remove your filter from the irb.20 interface -- you do not need it!  With some exceptions (on buggy/limited platforms) lo0 filters do not affect any transit traffic; they only affect traffic being processed by the routing engine.

```
interfaces {
  lo0 {
    unit 0 {
      family inet {
        filter {
          input REv4-in;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
policy-options {
  prefix-list ssh_allow {
    192.0.2.0/24;
  }
  prefix-list snmp_allow {
    192.0.2.0/24;
  }
}
firewall {
  family inet {
    filter REv4-in {
      term ssh_allow {
        from {
          protocol tcp;
          destination-port 22;
          source-prefix-list ssh_allow;
        }
        then {
          count ssh_allow;
          accept;
        }
      }
      term snmp_allow {
        from {
          protocol udp;
          destination-port 161;
          source-prefix-list snmp_allow;
        }
        then {
          count snmp_allow;
          accept;
        }
      }
      term control_default_discard {
        from {
          destination-port [ 22 161 ];
        }
        then {
          log;
          count control_default_discard;
          discard;
        }
      }
      term ELSE {
        then {
          count ELSE;
          accept;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```